# Проверка массива

Tags: массивы, php

Есть массив

```
$d = array("1","4","7");
```

и

```
$df = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
```

Если массив $df содержит хоть один элемент массива $d, то есть пересекается, то вернуть TRUE. Пробовал с помощью in_array:

```
   $isDom = (in_array($d,$df))?"df_yes":"df_no";
```

но так не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть для этого в PHP специальная функция:

```
array_intersect(array1, array2)
```

**Пример:**

```
$array1 = array ("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array ("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect ($array1, $array2);

$isDom = (count($result)>0) ? "df_yes" : "df_no";
```

Она возвращает элементы, которые есть и в первом массиве и во втором, т.е их пересечение.
А вообще это заняло бы у вас меньше времени, если б вбили в гугле **"пересечение массивов php"**

Comment: спасибо.буду знать